# Change size of video when video is playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, resize, playing

I am having a terrible time trying to figure out this when I'm sure it should be quite easy. So, I have a video on a website I am developing. I would like this video to resize to a different CSS (a bigger width/height) when it starts playing and resize back to normal (removing the CSS) when it pauses. How do I do this? I have tried jQuery with toggling function by adding/removing CSS. However the resize happens when clicked, whereas I would like to have it when it starts playing. Is there a way to do that?

The code is

```
<section>

<video controls preload="metadata" onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();">
</video>

</section>

CSS

section video {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: auto;
}

.largevideo {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
}

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("section video").click(function(){
        $("section video").toggleClass("largevideo");
    });
});

</script>
```

This would work, the only problem is that when I click the 'play' button the video does not get bigger. So I guess I either apply the same function to the 'play' button or I tag the function to when the video starts playing.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code you're using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize video when video starts/stops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350022/how-to-resize-video-when-video-starts-stops)

Answer (score 0):

please mention height and width like in video tag itself-

Comment: <video controls preload="metadata" onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" height='' width=''>
</video>

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.