# How to resize video when video starts/stops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I think I have the right code to make a video bigger when it starts playing and smaller when it pauses.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("section video").get(0).pause || $("section video").get(0).ended) {
        $("section video").click(function() {
            $("section video").animate({ width: "100%" }, 'slow')
            $("section video").queue(function(){
                $("section video").get(0).play();
            });
        });
        $("section video").animate({ width: "50%" }, 'slow')
    }
    else if ($("section video").get(0).play) {
        $("section video").click(function(){
            $("section video").animate({ width: "50%" }, 'slow')
            $("section video").queue(function(){
                $("section video").get(0).pause();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

However, it works when I click on it and it starts. But when I click on it again with the 'play' condition nothing happens. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo, it's **paused** and as far as I know there's no property for videos for getting the *playing* status.

Try with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var video = $('section video').get(0);

    video.onended = function(e) {
      $('section video').animate({ width: "50%" }, 'slow');
    }

    $('section video').click(function() {
        if(this.paused || this.ended){
           $('section video').animate({ width: "100%" }, 'slow');
           video.play();
        } else{
          $('section video').animate({ width: "50%" });
          video.pause();
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Sure you can make the video playing again once the animation is done:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var video = $('section video').get(0);

    video.onended = function(e) {
      $('section video').animate({ width: "50%" }, 'slow');
    }

    $('video').click(function() {
        if(this.paused || this.ended){
          $('section video').animate({
            width: "100%"
          },
          {
           duration: 'slow',
           complete: function(){
              video.play();
          }
          });
        } else{
          video.pause();
          $('section video').animate({ width: "50%" });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alessio! You literally saved my day!

Comment: What about the queue function? I would like the video to play when it becomes 100 per cent wider. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @LorenzoMassa Yes, sure, see the updated answer above ;)

Comment: Apparently I have not enough reputation to make it show the thumb-up, sorry :'(

Comment: Glad to have helped you! ;)